# How to make call to multiple services in parallel?

Tags: ros, rosservice, multithreading, parallel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 4 services which have are completely independent of each other.
I want to call them in parallel from another ros node.

But the all service call end consuming the time that they would use in sequence.
**Is there any way to call services parallelly or this is a ROS limitation?**

Please have a look at my code for VC++

```
void service1Thread(void *param) {
    printf(currentDateTime()+"Started service1Thread\n").c_str());
    float output =service1Client->compute(var1);
    printf((currentDateTime()+"Ended service1Thread\n").c_str());
    _endthread();
}

void service2Thread(void *param) {
    printf(currentDateTime()+"Started service2Thread\n").c_str());
    float output =service2Client->compute(var2);
    printf((currentDateTime()+"Ended service2Thread\n").c_str());
    _endthread();
}

void service3Thread(void *param) {
    printf(currentDateTime()+"Started service3Thread\n").c_str());
    float output =service3Client->compute(var3);
    printf((currentDateTime()+"Ended service3Thread\n").c_str());
    _endthread();
}

void service4Thread(void *param) {
    printf(currentDateTime()+"Started service4Thread\n").c_str());
    float output =service4Client->compute(var4);
    printf((currentDateTime()+"Ended service4Thread\n").c_str());
    _endthread();
}

int main(args[]) {
        printf((currentDateTime()+"Calling thread service1Thread\n").c_str());
    HANDLE handle1 = (HANDLE)_beginthread( service1Thread, 0, NULL);
        
        printf((currentDateTime()+"Calling thread service2Thread\n").c_str());
    HANDLE handle2= (HANDLE)_beginthread( service2Thread, 0, NULL);

    printf((currentDateTime()+"Calling thread service3Thread\n").c_str());
    HANDLE handle3 = (HANDLE)_beginthread( service3Thread, 0, NULL);

    printf((currentDateTime()+"Calling thread service4Thread\n").c_str());
    HANDLE handle4 = (HANDLE)_beginthread( service4Thread, 0, NULL);

    printf((currentDateTime()+"Waiting for all threads\n").c_str());
    HANDLE lpHandles[] = {handle1 ,handle2 ,handle3 ,handle4 };
    WaitForMultipleObjects(4,lpHandles,true,INFINITE);
    printf((currentDateTime()+"Finished waiting for all threads\n").c_str());

}

const std::string currentDateTime() {
    SYSTEMTIME st, lt;
    GetSystemTime(&st);
    char currentTime[84] = "";
    sprintf(currentTime,"[%d:%d:%d.%d] ", st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond , st.wMilliseconds);
    return string(currentTime); 
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218781/how-to-make-call-to-multiple-services-in-parallel?/) by [Anshul Vij](https://answers.ros.org/users/24316/anshul-vij/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a while ago but this question has answers [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/47049/how-to-make-two-calls-parallel/) and [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/258931/roscpp-service-calls-multithreading/)

---

Originally posted by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) with karma: 464 on 2018-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The link below to the multithreaded spinner is what you're looking for. Instead of spinning up only 1 thread to check and process requests, you can do N of them, where N is the input. This way multiple calls of the same service may be called at once or N different services in the same package at once.

Take care to lock resources.

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Multi-threaded_Spinning

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1